# Решения для управления базой данных

Tags: база-данных, веб-служба, интерфейс, облако, сервисы

Здравствуйте, подскажите, есть ли решения для разработки приложений управления базами данных с возможностью подключения плагинов, например, ролевой модели? Или есть ли готовые сервисы, на которых иммется возможность завести аккаунт, указать базу данных и настроить интерфейс под свои нужды?